# Why my capitalization of javascript string is not working

Tags: javascript

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var one = str.split('');

  for(var i = 0;i>one.length;i++) {
    one[i] = one[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + one[i].slice(1);
  }

  var final = one.join("");
  return final;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"); // yields "I'm a little tea pot", unchanged
```

Can you explain to me why it doesn't work? I'm supposed to capitalize first letters of every word in this string.

Comment: And what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: so what output do you get at the moment?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top**

Comment: i>one.length; correct this condition to i<one.length

Comment: You've split the string into characters rather than words.

Comment: I've actually been getting  the passed string, unchanged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 issues in your code,

- Your for loop is wrong, it should be `i < one.length`
- You're not splitting the words but the entire string.
- You have to put back the space between the words.

```js
    function titleCase(str) {
    var one = str.split(' ');
    
    for(var i = 0;i<one.length;i++) {
        one[i] = one[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + one[i].slice(1);        
    }
    
    var final = one.join(" ");
    return final;
}
    
alert(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following logical errors:

1) You are splitting the sting on every single letter instead of every word. Use. `split(' ')` instead of `.split('')`

2) You are checking for `i > one.length` which is never the case since `i` starts as `0`. You should do `i < one.length`